# error: expected an identifier. expected a valid attribute name

Tags: html, django

```
    {% for product in product %}
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src='/media/{{ product.get("image") }}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.get("product_name") }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ product.get("desc") }}</p>
            <button id="pr{{product.get("id")}}" class="btn btn-primary cart">Add To Cart</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was building a Django e-com platform and now I am getting this error for the image src tag

ERROR: Expected an identifier. |Expected a valid attribute name, but instead found " ' ", Which is not part of a valid attribute name.

How to fix this error?

Comment: Please always provide full error traceback and context. Like you template syntax is just wrong, if you are not using DTL state it clearly

Answer (score 0):

Check the value returned by product.get("image") to ensure it is a valid image path.

Maybe you need it more like this:

```
{% for product in products %}
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="/media/{{ product.image }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.product_name }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ product.desc }}</p>
            <button id="pr{{ product.id }}" class="btn btn-primary cart">Add To Cart</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

i.e. product.image vs product.get